# React close modal on click outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a basic modal using react without any library and it works perfectly, now when I click outside of the modal, I want to close the modal.

here is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-hellman-jqp9y?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) live preview

my index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showModal: !prevState.showModal
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Open Modal</button>
        {this.state.showModal && (
          <div className="modal">
            I'm a modal!
            <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>close modal</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code snippets here instead of just linking to a third party site

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without using `ref`, it would be a little tricky

Watch this [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-hofstadter-qtrtn)

Or

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    if (!this.state.showModal) {
      document.addEventListener("click", this.handleOutsideClick, false);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleOutsideClick, false);
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showModal: !prevState.showModal
    }));
  };

  handleOutsideClick = e => {
    if (!this.node.contains(e.target)) this.handleClick();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        ref={node => {
          this.node = node;
        }}
      >
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Open Modal</button>
        {this.state.showModal && (
          <div className="modal">
            I'm a modal!
            <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>close modal</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I used this technique happily for a custom drop down.  But code wise I might add a private variable to the class to hold the node value, to make this more TypeScript safe and relevant, the above writing to an unseen object on the class is very JavaScript-y.

Answer (score 40):

The easiest way to get this is to call the closeModal function in the wrapper and stop propagation in the actual modal

For example

```
<ModalWrapper onClick={closeModal} >
  <InnerModal onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()} /> 
</ModalWrapper>
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how to actually do this

Comment: where is the components ModalWrapper and InnerModal ??

Comment: Fyi `ModalWrapper` is a component that covers the whole screen and is transparent; it captures any "outside" click. `InnerModal` is the modal.

Comment: This is actually the right approach without going into too much complexity. A working example of this concept can be found -> https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-example-in-react-with-close-on-click-outside-oz8wb

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by creating a div for the modal backdrop which sits adjacent to the modal body. Make it cover the whole screen using position absolute and 100% height and width values.

That way the modal body is sitting over the backdrop. If you click on the modal body nothing happens because the backdrop is not receiving the click event. But if you click on the backdrop, you can handle the click event and close the modal.

The key thing is that the modal backdrop does not wrap the modal body but sits next to it. If it wraps the body then any click on the backdrop or the body will close the modal.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Modal = () => {
  const [showModal,setShowModal] = useState(false)

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={ () => setShowModal(true) }>Open Modal</button>
      { showModal && (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className='modal-backdrop' onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}></div>
          <div className="modal">
            <div>I'm a modal!</div>
            <button onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>close modal</button>
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Modal />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.modal-backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #252424cc;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
}
.modal {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin:20px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I will explain with functional components:

- first create ref to get a reference to the `modal` element

  ```
  import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

  const [isModalOpen,setIsModalOpen]=useState(false)
  const modalEl = useRef();

    <div className="modal" ref={modalEl} >
        I'm a modal!
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>close modal</button>
      </div>
  ```
- second in `useEffect` create an event handler to detect an event outside the modal element. For this we need to implement `capture phase` on an element. (explained here: [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing/74858576#74858576) ). Basically, we are going to register an event handler so that when the browser detects any event, browser will start to look for the event handlers from the top parent HTML element and if it finds it, it will call it.

  ```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (event) => {
      if (!modalEl.current) {
        return;
      }
      // if click was not inside of the element. "!" means not
      // in other words, if click is outside the modal element
      if (!modalEl.current.contains(event.target)) {
        setIsModalOpen(false);
      }
    };
    // the key is using the `true` option
    // `true` will enable the `capture` phase of event handling by browser
    document.addEventListener("click", handler, true);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handler);
    };
  }, []);
  ```

Comment: In `!modalEl.current.contains(event.target)` the property 'contains' does not exist on type 'never'.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the attached [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-rgb-noygb) for a working example.

You were almost there. Firstly, you need to do a callback function in your `handleClick()` that will add a `closeMenu` method to the document:

```
  handleClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showModal: true }, () => {
      document.addEventListener("click", this.closeMenu);
    });
  };
```

And then toggle the state inside `closeMenu()`:

```
  closeMenu = () => {
    this.setState({ menuOpen: false }, () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeMenu);
    });
  }
```

Any time you click outside of the component, then it'll close it. :)

Comment: No worries. Please upvote and accept as the correct answer if this helped you :)

Comment: But, the modal will close even if we click on the modal. I want the modal to close only if clicked outside. @A7DC

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

Need to use `e.stopPropagation` to prevent loop

```
handleClick = e => {
 if (this.state.showModal) {
   this.closeModal();
   return;
 }
 this.setState({ showModal: true });
 e.stopPropagation();
 document.addEventListener("click", this.closeModal);
};
```

then:

```
closeModal = () => {
 this.setState({ showModal: false });
 document.removeEventListener("click", this.closeModal);
};
```

Hope will help

Comment: Need to click inside modal without closing it.

Comment: I used this for a dropdown list and works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = React.useState(false)

React.useEffect(() => {
  document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
    setShowModal(false)
  })
})

return <>
  <Modal
    style={{ display: showModal ? 'block' : 'none'}}
    onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
  />
  <button onClick={(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    setShowModal(true)
  }}>Show Modal</button>
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:
BTW, I"m a junior dev, so check it, GL.

In index.html:

```
<div id="root"></div>
<div id="modal-root"></div>
```

In index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ModalBase />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("modal-root")
);
```

In the App.js:

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
 {showModal && (
  <ModalBase setShowModal={setShowModal}>
    {/*Your modal goes here*/}
    <YourModal setShowModal={setShowModal} />
  </ModalBase>
```

In the modal container:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const modalRoot: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("modal-root");

const Modal: React.FC<{
children: React.ReactNode;
setShowModal: React.Dispatch<boolean>;
}> = ({ children, setShowModal }) => {
  const [el] = useState(document.createElement("div"));
  const outClick = useRef(el);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOutsideClick = (
      e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent> | MouseEvent
    ) => {
      const { current } = outClick;
      console.log(current.childNodes[0], e.target);
      if (current.childNodes[0] === e.target) {
        setShowModal(false);
      }
    };
    if (modalRoot) {
      modalRoot.appendChild(el);
      outClick.current?.addEventListener(
        "click",
        (e) => handleOutsideClick(e),
        false
      );
    }
    return () => {
      if (modalRoot) {
        modalRoot.removeChild(el);
        el.removeEventListener("click", (e) => handleOutsideClick(e), false);
      }
    };
  }, [el, setShowModal]);

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(children, el);
};

export default Modal;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the event.target.className if it's contain the parent class you can close the Modal as below, in case you clicked inside the popup **div** it will not closed:

```
  handleClick = () => {
    if (e.target.className === "PARENT_CLASS") {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            showModal: false
        }));
    }

    // You should use e.stopPropagation to prevent looping
    e.stopPropagation();
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following onClick method,

```
<div className='modal-backdrop' onClick={(e) => {
      if (e.target.className === 'modal-backdrop') {
        setShowModal(false)
      }
    }}></div>
<div className="modal">
   <div>I'm a modal!</div>
     <button onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>close modal</button>
   </div>
</div>

.modal-backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #252424cc;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
}
```