# Close modal window on first click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I have a modal window on my website, which is implemented using the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal.

Inside the modal window there is a Select (https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/select) with which the user can select the desired product.

The implementation can be found here https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/xenodochial-gates-v8s8cg

The problem is the following:

1. Follow the link above and click the Settings button (a modal window will open);
2. Click Select default (a list of elements to select will open);
3. Now click outside the modal window. First, Select will close, and the second click will close the modal window;

Question: how can I make the modal window close with one click?

There is also a similar problem, but as I understand it, this is a consequence of the previous one:

1. Follow the link above and click the Settings button (a modal window will open);
2. Click Select default (a list of elements to select will open);
3. Click within the modal window, but outside the Select (Select will close)
4. But to close the modal window, you still need to click outside it twice.

Tell me how to solve this problem

```
export default function App() {
  const [settingsIsOpen, setSettingsIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <>
        <button
          onClick={() => setSettingsIsOpen(!settingsIsOpen)}
          type="button"
        >
          Settings
        </button>
        <Settings
          settingsIsOpen={settingsIsOpen}
          setSettingsIsOpen={setSettingsIsOpen}
        />
      </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Full code example at the link from codesandbox

Comment: check this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017954/react-close-modal-on-click-outside